# Copy Word into Excel and clear Clipboard message IN WORD

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am copying from word doc to excel worksheet.

However I cannot not get the Word App to quit without the "Large amount of data in clipboard" dialog box popping up at the end.

```
Sub TKButton()

Dim wrdApp As Object
Dim wrdDoc As Object

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True

Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(thisisthefilepath.doc)

wrdApp.Selection.WholeStory
wrdApp.Selection.Copy

Sheets("TK").Paste Destination:=Sheets("TK").Range("A2")

wrdApp.Documents.Close (False)
wrdApp.Quit
Set wrdApp = Nothing
```

I have tried:

```
Application.displayAlerts = False

wrdApp.displayAlerts = False

wrdApp.cutcopymode = False
```

Nothing seems to stop it from happening.

Comment: OR just add `wrdApp.Application.CutCopyMode = False` before the line to close the document.

Comment: @BruceWayne wrdApp.Application.CutCopyMode = False gives me a runtime error object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: What about just `Application.cutCopyMode = False`? (Or alternatively, skip the clipboard completely and just set the two ranges equal to eachother?)

Comment: @BruceWayne it doesn't throw an error nor stop the problem.

Comment: I don't see you using the `.putinClipboard` method anywhere. But I'm the one that doesn't read.... -1

Comment: Before closing, what if you copy a tiny bit of data?  Hopefully then it'll be so little the prompt isn't necessary.

Comment: Word doesn't have CutCopyMode, that's an Excel thing. Copying a single character works well.